# Maximum call stack size exceeded when replacing prototype with ES6 Proxy

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, es6-proxy

I have a typescript class decorator

```
export function Profile(config: ProfilerConfig): ClassDecorator {
  return function <TFunction extends Function> (target: TFunction) {
    logToConsole = config.logToConsole || false;
    Object.setPrototypeOf(
      target.prototype,
      new Proxy(target.prototype , handler)
    );
  };
}
```

And I am trying to replace the prototype with a proxy of the target prototype and I am getting

```
ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

But I am not seeing any apparent recursion. When I use

```
target.prototype = new Proxy(target.prototype , handler)
```

this does not happen. Any ideas ?

Comment: Because this is JavaScript, can you add a snippet that shows the problem, please? We need to be able to reproduce it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
target.prototype = new Proxy(target.prototype , handler)
```

This sets the `prototype` of `target` to a proxy of itself.

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(
  target.prototype,
  new Proxy(target.prototype , handler)
);
```

This sets the `prototype` of `target.prototype` to a proxy of `target.prototype`. Then you've got a cyclic dependency: `Object.getPrototypeOf(target.prototype) == proxy(target.prototype)`, so when JavaScript tries to walk the prototype chain it will be stuck in an infinite loop of calling the Proxy handler over and over.

---

I think `Object.setPrototypeOf()` doesn't make any sense here anyway. This function is meant to set the prototype of an *instance*. You seem to be trying to set the prototype of a constructor, i.e. the `constructor.prototype` object that will be inherited from when creating an instance by `new constructor`. You need to assign the `prototype` of the constructor directly as in your first snippet.

Comment: I have tried that, but the proxy isn't triggered that way :/, meaning the __ proto __ is still Object and not a Proxy

Comment: @MarijanSpasenovski See my edited answer. `target` is a Function, so I'm assuming it is the constructor from which you will be creating an object later. If that is the case, you need to set the target's `prototype`, not its `__proto__`. If you want to only modify the prototype of an instance, pass that instance in instead of the instance's constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that makes a lot of sense. Too bad I can't set the target's prototype directly after a class has been defined because I have targeted es6 and it's not allowed to.

Answer (score 2):

This is not specific to `target.prototype`, this would happen to any object:

```
const o = {};
Object.setPrototypeOf(o, new Proxy(o, {}));
o.property;
```

Where would you expect the `property` to come from. It could be either an own property of `o`, or it could be inherited from its prototype: the proxy says it is not an own property, but it could be inherited from its prototype… Which leads us down the rabbit hole of recursive `get` accesses. You can try providing a trap for that on your proxy handler, and you can use it for logging or debugging the recursion.

Notice that `Object.setPrototypeOf(o, o)` throws an exception to forbid cyclic inheritance chains, but the proxy circumvents that.

Answer (score 1):

Maximum call stack exceed here:

`Object.setPrototypeOf(
    target.prototype,
    new Proxy(target.prototype , handler)
);`

Let's look what is happened here: you want to add proxy to `target.prototype`. I am not sure, if it's okay, because what MDN says about target of proxy:

> A target object to wrap with Proxy. It can be any sort of object, including a native array, a function, or even another proxy.

But prototype for object is an `any sort of object`, so let's suppose you can do it.

Then, you try to add a proxied prototype as a prototype for a targets prototype (sorry for that)). Circled links like that is a good way to get a stack exceeded. So here it is.

I think some JS-way workaround with simple getter will help you a lot:

```
Object.defineProperty(proto, 'foo', get: function() { ...} );
```